# Get day of week in PHP with strftime()

Tags: php

What is the most reliable way to get the day of the week?

- `strftime("%u")` (1 = moonday to 7 = Sunday)
- `strftime("%w")` (0 = sunday to 6 = moonday)

Comment: There is no "better" way. Your approach should best match the requirements of the software, and those requirements vary. That said, the equivalent of `date('N')` is `strftime("%u")`, and if your code already relies on `date('N')` results, you would want to use that. There's really no point though.

Comment: How would you define 'better'?

Comment: See answer below. strftime("%u") is now equivalent to date('N')

Comment: By "better" I mean "recommended by PHP community". Thanks. I made my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the behavior of `%u` is not consistent across operating systems (see the warning here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php and multiple reports of the problem in search results).

If you prefer to use strftime then stick to `%w`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow the advice. I also think it makes more sense to have index 0 for Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you **need** to use %w (look here why : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

So it is something like :

```
function get_week_day()
{
    $tmp = strftime('%w');
    if ($tmp == 0)
    {
         return 7;
    }
    return $tmp;
}
```

Comment: This could be a substitute to `date('N')`, but it's not my need. Thanks anyway.